# why would a condensate confine any excitation that has nontrivial mutual statistics with it?

Tags: condensed-matter

This seems to be a very general argument in condensed matter physics.  Could somebody give an intuitive argument for it?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe due to exchange energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we condense the bosons, we mean the phase angle $\theta$ of the boson matter wave develops a long-range order across the system, such that there is a rigidity of the boson phase. The phase rigidity can be described by a gradient term in the Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{\rho}{2} (\partial_x\theta)^2.$$
Any twist (variance) of the phase $\theta$ in the space will cost some energy due to this gradient term. This energy cost originates from the kinetic energy of the boson because the momentum of the boson is proportional to $\partial_x\theta$ in the condensate.

Now if we introduce a pair of vortices to the condensate, the boson phase will be twisted around the vortices. The phase twist is a consequence of the non-trivial mutual braiding statistics between the vortex and the boson. In order to minimize the energy cost in the condensate, the phase twist will be concentrated to a narrow region between the vortices, as illustrated in the picture below (the lines are the equal phase contours).

[image: equal phase lined between a pair of vortices]

Otherwise, if we spread the phase twist throughout the system, it will cost too much energy (proportional to the linear system size). Since the phase twist is concentrated along a line between the vortices, the energy will increase linearly with the distance between the vortices, therefore the vortices are confined.

Any particle that has non-trivial mutual statistics with the particle in the condensate can be viewed as a vortex in the condensate which is then confining.

Comment: Great explanation Yizhuang! Thanks a lot for taking the pain to draw a picture! So the keys are (1) any particle that has non-trivial mutual statistics with the particle in the condensate can be viewed as a vortex in the condensate (2) to minimize the kinetic energy cost the phase twist must be concentrated along a line between the vortices giving rise to an energy cost linearly proportional to the distance between the vortices.